# SQL query duplicates, self-join, and calculated field

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I'm putting together a report to track latency in a SQL Availability Group. I need to find the difference between two times. I have server1, database1 and time1. I need to compare it to server2, database1, and time2. The data is stored in a table, and new data will be appended to the table. The query I'm trying to create will get these new entries (the field Hardened_time_MS_Diff will be NULL) and I need to get the difference between the times returned for the Primary and Secondary servers. Here's an example of the data:

```
Server_name  Database_name  Last_Hardened_Time
Server1      ABC            2015-10-08 10:10:05.180
Server2      ABC            2015-10-08 10:10:05.643
```

My query to get the Hardened_time_MS_Diff values looks like this:

```
Select a1.server_name,  a1.database_name, 
Case when a1.Last_Hardened_Time >= a2.Last_Hardened_Time
       then
         DATEDIFF (MS, a2.Last_Hardened_Time, a1.Last_Hardened_Time)
       Else
         DATEDIFF (MS, a1.Last_Hardened_Time, a2.Last_Hardened_Time)
       End as Hardened  
   FROM [database].[dbo].[ag_latency] a1
           JOIN ag_latency a2
          ON a1.database_name = a2.database_name
    AND a1.server_name <> a2.server_name
          where a1.Hardened_time_MS_Diff is NULL
```

Right now it's returning some crazy numbers, and duplicates. The first run it'll work fine. The second run my data will look correct only for the servers whose Last_Hardened_time hasn't changed. If it changed I'll get an absolutely huge number for the second batch like this:

```
Server_name  Database_name  Last_Hardened_Time       Hardened_time_MS_Diff
Server1      ABC            2015-10-09 12:00:05.013  26
Server2      ABC            2015-10-09 12:00:05.040  26
Server1      ABC            2015-10-09 12:15:07.843  -902803
Server2      ABC            2015-10-09 12:15:07.877  -902863
```

How can I get this to do what I want it to do?

Also, the part to get the data is in Powershell, so if there's an easier way to manipulate the data table in PoSH and then push that data down let me know.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Simply answer your question, your join clause won't work when you have multiple pair of timestamps - it will join not only the row1-row2 and row3-row4, but also join row1-row4 and row2-row3, which the later two doesn't make sense to your report.

One possible solution would be eliminate any time difference greater than a threshold (say 1000 MilliSec, according to your sample data). So your where clause would look like

```
where a1.Hardened_time_MS_Diff is NULL AND (DATEDIFF (MS, a2.Last_Hardened_Time, a1.Last_Hardened_Time) < 1000 AND DATEDIFF (MS, a2.Last_Hardened_Time, a1.Last_Hardened_Time) > -1000)
```

Another solution would be more robust, but requires you to change your table schema. You need to add a column to the table, indicate which 2 rows are paired. For example, assign 1 to first two rows and 2 to last two rows, and then join table a1 and a2 by this column.

```
Key  Server_name  Database_name  Last_Hardened_Time       Hardened_time_MS_Diff
1    Server1      ABC            2015-10-09 12:00:05.013  26
1    Server2      ABC            2015-10-09 12:00:05.040  26
2    Server1      ABC            2015-10-09 12:15:07.843  -902803
2    Server2      ABC            2015-10-09 12:15:07.877  -902863
```

For the powershell part, can you please elaborate what you need more specifically?

Henry

Comment: Thank you for the reply! I'm confused though as to why it's joining on more than the two new rows; my query should filter for only rows that have the Hardened_time_MS_Diff as NULL, and thus not compute on the rows that have already been computed. I feel it should be working. As for filtering over a certain difference, it can be many minutes, so unfortunately that won't work. I'm intrigued by your suggestion of having a key; I can do that on the PowerShell side and then after the computation in SQL I can NULL it, so only new rows that haven't been computed have the key. I'll also try that.

Comment: I am glad that my analysis is somewhat useful to you. The bottom line is the join - as long as you can join the "correct" pair of records, the rest would be simple. Good luck!